# node.js - can't connect to localhost

Tags: node.js

I have created a node.js chat site, with the following code :

```
var net = require("net");

var chatServer = net.createServer(),
clients = [];

chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
   client.write('Welcome');
   console.log("Connection is received!");

   clients.push(client);

   client.on('data', function (data) {
       for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
           clients[i].write(data + "\n");
       }
   });

   client.on('end', function() {
      client.end();
   });
});

chatServer.listen(8888);
```

But when I try to connect to localhost:8888, it just keep load till the server is closed.

I figure it out that the following code work perfectly :

```
var net = require("net");

var chatServer = net.createServer();

chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.write('Hi!');

    client.end();
});

chatServer.listen(8888);
```

So what I did wrong in the chat code?

**EDIT:** OK, So I actually figured out that when I connect to the server it actually log "Connection is received" which means I can connect to the server, but what I see is the browser trying to load the page. and I cant see the actual server.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing this line which will make server un-responsive.

```
client.end();
```

Comment: when you want to end the response to client .